# Mixing abbreviations styles with glossaries-extra

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

I am trying to have a mix of small caps and lower case italic abbreviations/acronyms in thesis. I am using glossaries-extra and trying to create a new abbreviation category 'acronymLC', however when I change the style for one category it seems to override the style in the text. I have provided a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[automake,acronym,nomain,shortcuts=other]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{short-sc-desc}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronymLC]{short-em-desc}
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrscfont}[1]{\normalfont\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\glsxtremfont}[1]{\normalfont\textit{\normalfont #1}}
\newacronym[description={I want this to be small caps but \gls{def} should be lower case italics}]{abc}{abc}{Alpha Bravo Charlie}
\newabbreviation[category=acronymLC,description={I want this to be lower case italics but \gls{abc} should be small caps.}]{def}{def}{delta echo foxtrot}
\begin{document}
I have two acronyms \gls{abc} and \gls{def}. I would like the first to be small caps and the second to be lower case italics.
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Also I want to get rid of the bold font in the glossary, this has been answered before but I think I am making a mistake in implementing it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a combination of problems here. The first may be a bug in the `short-sc-desc` style which can be fixed with:

```
\renewabbreviationstyle{short-sc-desc}
{%
  \renewcommand*{\CustomAbbreviationFields}{%
    name={\protect\glsxtrinlinefullformat{\the\glslabeltok}{}},
    sort={\the\glsshorttok},
    first={\protect\glsxtrfirstscfont{\the\glsshorttok}},
    firstplural={\protect\glsxtrfirstscfont{\the\glsshortpltok}},
    text={\protect\glsxtrscfont{\the\glsshorttok}},
    plural={\protect\glsxtrscfont{\the\glsshortpltok}},
    description={\the\glslongtok}}%
  \renewcommand*{\GlsXtrPostNewAbbreviation}{%
    \glssetattribute{\the\glslabeltok}{regular}{true}}%
}
{%
  \GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleFmts{short-desc}%
  \renewcommand*{\abbrvpluralsuffix}{\protect\glsxtrscsuffix}%
  \renewcommand*\glsabbrvfont[1]{\glsxtrscfont{##1}}%
  \renewcommand*\glsfirstabbrvfont[1]{\glsxtrfirstscfont{##1}}%
}
```

There's no command `\glsxtremfont` provided by `glossaries-extra` so your definition

```
\newcommand*{\glsxtremfont}[1]{\normalfont\textit{\normalfont #1}}
```

isn't used. (My fault for not using a more consistent naming scheme. I think it came from adding the `em` style later and not comparing it with the `sc` and `sm` styles.) It also counteracts the effect of `\textit` with `\normalfont`. I think you perhaps intended:

```
\renewcommand*{\glsabbrvemfont}[1]{\normalfont\textit{#1}}
```

The other problem is related to the `\gls` in the description. I'm not sure why it's occurring here. It's not exactly a [nested link](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:nested) but seems to be exhibiting the same kind of behaviour. It can be fixed by changing `\gls` to `\glsps` (short form) or `\glspt` (text form). With this particular style there's no real difference between `\glsps` and `\glspt`.

Here's the complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[automake,acronym,nomain,shortcuts=other]{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries

\renewabbreviationstyle{short-sc-desc}
{%
  \renewcommand*{\CustomAbbreviationFields}{%
    name={\protect\glsxtrinlinefullformat{\the\glslabeltok}{}},
    sort={\the\glsshorttok},
    first={\protect\glsxtrfirstscfont{\the\glsshorttok}},
    firstplural={\protect\glsxtrfirstscfont{\the\glsshortpltok}},
    text={\protect\glsxtrscfont{\the\glsshorttok}},
    plural={\protect\glsxtrscfont{\the\glsshortpltok}},
    description={\the\glslongtok}}%
  \renewcommand*{\GlsXtrPostNewAbbreviation}{%
    \glssetattribute{\the\glslabeltok}{regular}{true}}%
}
{%
  \GlsXtrUseAbbrStyleFmts{short-desc}%
  \renewcommand*{\abbrvpluralsuffix}{\protect\glsxtrscsuffix}%
  \renewcommand*\glsabbrvfont[1]{\glsxtrscfont{##1}}%
  \renewcommand*\glsfirstabbrvfont[1]{\glsxtrfirstscfont{##1}}%
}

\renewcommand*{\glsxtrscfont}[1]{\normalfont\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\glsabbrvemfont}[1]{\normalfont\textit{#1}}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{short-sc-desc}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronymLC]{short-em-desc}

\newacronym[description={I want this to be small caps but \glsps{def}
should be lower case italics}]{abc}{abc}{Alpha Bravo Charlie}

\newabbreviation[category=acronymLC,description={I want this to be
lower case italics but \glsps{abc} should be small
caps.}]{def}{def}{delta echo foxtrot}

\begin{document}
I have two acronyms \gls{abc} and \gls{def}. I would like the first
to be small caps and the second to be lower case italics.
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

Comment: Thanks Nicola, this is fantastic. The glossaries-extra manual did mention glsxtremfont multiple times which is why I attempted to use it.

Comment: @JonathanBrodrick Thanks for pointing it out. I'm sorry about the confusion. I'll get the manual fixed.